# Objective-C Block Literal Syntax Principle

Tags: c++, objective-c-blocks

i'm a iOS programer from china, I'm so sorry that i can't make an exact title for this question, but i'll try to describe it detailed. If there are any one can help me to change the title, i'm very thankful about that. Sorry for my bad English.

When i using `clang -rewrite-objc` to see the source code about the Block Syntax, i found there is something that i can't understand. Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void (^blk)() = ^ {
    };
    blk();
}
```

And the core source code is

```
struct __block_impl {
  void *isa;
  int Flags;
  int Reserved;
  void *FuncPtr;
};

struct __main_block_impl_0 {
  struct __block_impl impl;
  struct __main_block_desc_0* Desc;
  __main_block_impl_0(void *fp, struct __main_block_desc_0 *desc, int flags=0) {
    impl.isa = &_NSConcreteStackBlock;
    impl.Flags = flags;
    impl.FuncPtr = fp;
    Desc = desc;
  }
};

static void __main_block_func_0(struct __main_block_impl_0 *__cself) {

 }

static struct __main_block_desc_0 {
  size_t reserved;
  size_t Block_size;
} __main_block_desc_0_DATA = { 0, sizeof(struct __main_block_impl_0)};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 void (*blk)() = ((void (*)())&__main_block_impl_0((void *)__main_block_func_0, &__main_block_desc_0_DATA));
 ((void (*)(__block_impl *))((__block_impl *)blk)->FuncPtr)((__block_impl *)blk);
}
```

In the main function, when i call the blk(), the source code cast blk and take the FuncPtr by this code

```
((__block_impl *)blk)->FuncPtr)
```

I can't really understand that, is it supposed to do? In my opinion, i prefer to use

```
(((__main_block_impl_0 *)blk ->impl).FuncPtr)
```

I don't really know more about C++, if there is anyone who can help me to understand the principle of this code, i'll be very thankful. Thanks for you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `struct __main_block_impl_0`'s first member (`impl`) is a `struct __block_impl`. So the location of the `struct __main_block_impl_0` is the same as the location of the `struct __block_impl` that is its first member. If you have the pointer to one you can just treat it as a pointer to the other.